# Parse Value from XML Tag

Tags: xml, parsing, grep

I am trying to parse out a value (**21.0**) out of an XML tag, `<value type="float">21.0</value>`.

**XML Text (xml_parse.txt)**

```
<OBSERVATIONS type="dict">
  <air_temp_value_1 type="dict">
    <date_time type="str">2019-07-25T10:35:00Z</date_time>
    <value type="float">21.0</value>
  </air_temp_value_1>
</OBSERVATIONS>
```

**Attempted Code**

```
cat xml_parse.txt | sed -nr 's/.* OBSERVATIONS="([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` processes the input line by line. XML is not line based; use an XML-aware tool.

For example, using `xmllint`:

```
xmllint -xpath '/OBSERVATIONS/air_temp_value_1/value/text()' file.xml
```

Or, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) (a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) I happen to maintain) you can write

```
open file.xml ;
echo (/OBSERVATIONS/air_temp_value_1/value) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to use sed or some other line-oriented processor, a more appropriate tool is [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) that observes the xml structure .

Your task is accomplished by

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/OBSERVATIONS/air_temp_value_1/value' -v . -n xml_parse.txt
```

It extracts the value from an xml element specified by its xpath (which is a syntax to select data [elements, attributes, text, ...] from an xml tree.

This of course assumes that `xmlstarlet` has been installed first. Possibly it is already available on your system.

Alternatively you can rely on an xslt processor and the appropriate stylesheet.

PS:
I have no affiliation with xmlstarlet other than having used it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"[<>]" '/float/ {print $3}' xml_parse.txt
21.0
```